# NetBeans: how to add ScrollBar to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I am developing a small desktop application in NetBeans. On my UI, I place a JPanel and put a single JLabel on it. The content of this JLabel is generated dynamically, so if the content is very large then it goes out of screen.So is there any way in which I can specify a fixed size for the JPanel and of course ScrollBars should appear  when the text exceeds the screen size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use JScrollPane to contain Your big JPanel.

Answer (score 8):

You will have to just pass Component reference to the JScrollPane Constructor.
It will work fine. You can definetely use JScrollPane
The following is the sudo example of the JScrollPane for JPanel from my past project. Hope it will be useful for you.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Frame01
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable ()
        {
            public void run ()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("panel demo");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                Container c = frame.getContentPane();
                panel.setSize(100,100);
                panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1000,1));
                for(int i = 0; i<1000;i++)
                panel.add(new JLabel("JLabel "+i));

                JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(panel);
                c.add(jsp);
                frame.setSize(100,100);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`so in case when the contents are very large it goes out of screen`, maybe you have to look for `TextComponents` as [JTextArea or JEditorPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html), tutorial contains example including basic usage for [JScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Answer (score 2):

In the Navigator, click on JPanel with the right mouse button --> Enclose In --> Scroll Pane.

Done!, You have now scrolls